# Sinatra not binding to right port

Tags: sinatra, port, openshift

I'm using Openshift and Sinatra to host my website. But it's not binding to the right port.

```
set :port, ENV["OPENSHIFT_RUBY_PORT"]
set :port, ENV["OPENSHIFT_RUBY_IP"]
...
puts ENV["OPENSHIFT_RUBY_PORT"]
puts settings.port
puts ENV["OPENSHIFT_RUBY_IP"]
puts settings.bind
```

This returns the correct output. But when the server actually starts...

```
Listening on localhost:9292, CTRL+C to stop
```

The error:

```
no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)
```

How do I get it to bind to the right port?

Comment: Are you sure no other server is running on the same port? What is the `OPENSHIFT_RUBY_PORT` setting that is getting passed?

Comment: `OPENSHIFT_RUBY_PORT` is 8080.

Comment: How are you starting the server? Can you provide a sample script for reproduction?

Comment: The deploy script is just `bundle exec rackup` and config.ru is `require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

Bundler.require

require './main'
run Sinatra::Application`

Comment: main is the Sinatra app script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`set :port, ...` sets the port for Sinatra’s builtin server, but you are using `rackup`, so this setting is not used (9292 is the default port for Rack).

You can use the `-p` or `--port` options to `rackup` to set the port. From the command line you can do:

```
$ bundle exec rackup -p $OPENSHIFT_RUBY_PORT
```

You can also specify command line options in the first line of the `config.ru`, but I don’t think you can specify environment variables there.

If you want to avoid specifying the port on the command line, you may need to create a wrapper script that reads the environment variables and calls `rackup`.

Comment: And in the case you run Sinatra in docker container, let add option `-o 0.0.0.0` next to `-p $OPENSHIFT_RUBY_PORT`